how to animation with xarray dataset and cartopy projection with a colorbar?
How can I make an animation with xarray dataset which is projected on to a PlateCarree projection that includes a colorbar?

I have spent some time trying to answer this question, and some other answers elsewhere on stack overflow were useful but incomplete.

I am answering my own question for future reference for myself and for other if they find it useful
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# open the tutorial data
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset('air_temperature')

# Create a new figure
fig = plt.figure()

# Create an axes for the plot with the cartopy PlateCarree projection
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

#arguments
plot_args = {
    'transform':ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    'vmin': ds.air.quantile(0.01), # 1st percentile
    'vmax': ds.air.quantile(0.99),
    'cmap': 'RdBu_r',
    'add_colorbar': False #important otherwise replots multitude of colorbars
}

default_gridlines_kw = {'linewidth' : 1.5,
            'color' : 'silver',
            'alpha': 0.5, 
            'linestyle':'--',
            'xlabel_style': {'size':8},
            'ylabel_style': {'size':8}
            }

# Define an update function that will be called for each frame
def animate(frame):
    ax.clear()# can be necessary if some areas are nan... but unnecessary with the tutorial complete dataset without any gaps
        # ax.set_facecolor('darkslategray') # another useful parameter when some areas are nan, unnecesaary with the tutorial dataset
    ds.air.isel(time=frame).plot(ax=ax, **plot_args)
    ax.coastlines()
    # to draw the gridline in cartopy you need to tell it what projection you are using
    #but also you need to tell it to draw_labels=True as some projections don't have them 
    #or are confusing to draw
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, **default_gridlines_kw)
    

# Create the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=range(100), interval=200, repeat=True)

#define the colorbar. The colorbar method needs a mappable object from which to take the colorbar
cbar = fig.colorbar(ds.air.isel(time=0).plot(**plot_args))

# Save the animation as an mp4 file
ani.save('myanimation.mp4', writer='ffmpeg')


